# Spring controller test fails despite url working

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test a basic controller:

```
@Autowired
DAOInterface db;

@RequestMapping(value = "/postdb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String postdb(
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id
) {
    db.addEntry(id);
    return "Added " + id + ".";
}
```

This url works as when I access it, it adds it to a db and I get the string output as a response.

I am trying to create a simple unit test for it:

```
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
DAOInterface daoInterface;

@Test
public void shouldReturnA200() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/postdb?id=3"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

But instead I get the following

```
MockHttpServletRequest:


    HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /postdb
       Parameters = {id=[3]}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Not sure why I it's working whenever I try and access it but fails when running this test. I don't see any issues. Might it be because I'm not using any headers or a formal response body/view and rather just outputting a String?

EDIT = It works when I add 
                `.contextPath("/postdb"))`.. not sure if that's the correct way but when I write another test and dont include any request paramters, that test gives a 200 instead of a 400 or 404....

Comment: typo - `posttodb` not found. Should be `postdb`

Comment: Did you tried the test with the absolute URL, e.g. http: // localhost:8080/app-name/postdb?id=3 ?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado It wasa typo when I was writing the question. Edited the typo.

Comment: @Flocke Tried that and still same result

Comment: You may need `.contextPath("/").servletPath("/")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837872/how-to-set-servlet-path-for-every-request-through-mockmvc

Comment: @Stewart Tried that and getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context path must not end with a '/'`

Comment: Have you tried adding: 
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

Comment: Do you configure/setup your mockmvc correctly?? (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html ... before (each) test)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
DAOInterface db;

@RequestMapping(value = "/postdb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> postdb(@RequestParam(required = true) String id) {
    db.addEntry(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Added " + id + ".", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnA200() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/postdb?id=3")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is working fine  for me

public class FirstWebController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postdb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String postdb(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id) {
    System.out.println("idddddddddddd "+id);
    return "Added " + id + ".";
}
```

}

Test class is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class FirstWebControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    static class FirstWebControllerTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public FirstWebController firstWebController() {
            return new FirstWebController();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private FirstWebController firstWebController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(firstWebController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnA200() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/postdb?id=3")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: and Test class is

Answer (score 0):

Try adding query parameter as below:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnA200() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/postdb).param("id", "3"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```